# is there any difference if initializing a string type variable with the same letter by using raw_input or just assignment?(Python 2.7)

Tags: python, string, identity, raw-input

When I tried to find the indexes of certain letter in a string,I wrote this piece of code. If I input 'a' and give this value into **lettera**, for **indexa** and **indexb**, they should have the same results.However, **indexb**=[0,3]and **indexa**=[]. I don't see why. Does raw_input() have something special? The python version I'm using is 2.7, can someone help me?

```
word='abca'
lettera=raw_input("please input:")
letterb='a'
print 'letterb=',letterb
print 'lettera=',lettera
indexa=[]
indexb=[]
for i,x in enumerate(word) :
    if x is letterb:
        indexb.append(i)
print 'indexb=',indexb

for i,x in enumerate(word) :
    if x is lettera:
        indexa.append(i)
print 'indexa=',indexa
```

Comment: Good question though

Comment: @Y.Chen Try to put this test in your script, before building the indices arrays `print lettera is letterb` — the `is` operator is quite different from the `==` operator, the latter tests for equality, the former tests for identity.  It seems that your interpreter `raw_input` doesn't reuse the cached object for `a`. — if you want to get the same results, test for equality, using `==`, using `is` is reserved for _very_ particular issues.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `is`. Whether or not two references to a short string are references to the same exact object is implementation-dependent. Use `==` instead.

```
for i,x in enumerate(word) :
    if x == letterb:
        indexb.append(i)
print 'indexb=',indexb
```

When the code is compiled, the values of both `letterb` and `word` are known; this would appear to allow your Python implementation to re-use the  object referenced by `letterb` for `x` while iterating over `word`. `lettera`, though, is created at run-time, and the interpreter simply creates a new object rather than searching through the objects in memory to see if there is already an object for `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

i am using python 2.7 too and i see no problem here, they are exactly the same.

```
>>> indexa == indexb
True
>>>
```

[image: code and output]

Comment: You have misunderstood the question

Comment: Have you read my comment to the OP? they tests for identity, not equality.